# My Login and Register Page

Tags: php, html, sql, authentication

My Login Page:

```
<form id="login">
Username<input type="text" name="userid"/><br/><br/>
Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
<input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
{
 /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
 if(form.userid.value == "myuserid" && form.pswrd.value == "mypswrd")
  {
    window.open('target.html')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
  }
 else
 {
   alert("Error Password or Username")/*displays error message*/
  }
}
</script>
```

My Register Page:

```
<h1>Register</h1>
<form id="registration">
<label>Username:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="username" required="required"><br/>
<label>Password:</label><br/>
<input type="password" name="password" required="required"><br/>
<label>Email:</label><br/>
<input type="email" name="email" required="required"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
Already have an account?<br/>
<a href="login.html">Login</a>
```

My PHP page:

```
<?php
echo "<h1>Register</h1>\n"; 
echo "<form id=\"registration\">\n"; 
echo "<label>Username:</label><br/>\n"; 
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" required=\"required\"><br/>\n"; 
echo "<label>Password:</label><br/>\n"; 
echo "<input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" required=\"required\"><br/>\n"; 
echo "<label>Email:</label><br/>\n"; 
echo "<input type=\"email\" name=\"email\" required=\"required\"><br/>\n"; 
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Register\"/>\n"; 
echo "</form>\n";
?>
```

My SQL page:

```
CREATE DATABASE user_register;
USE user_register;

CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
```

When I click Register, nothing happens. Do u guys have any feedback for me on what to do? When i click the button, the search bar on the top of the page changes, but nothing else... I need help with something, if anything is actually incorrect. The Login Page and Register Page is HTML, and the others are self explanatory.

Comment: Where is the PHP code that handles the SQL?

Comment: There is... a lot missing here. Some things you are completely off-base with; you can't validate the username and password in javascript!  Here looks to be a [decent tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) on creating this kind of thing in php.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get the registration form working is to include method and action attributes here:

```
<form id="registration">
```

For example:

```
<form id="registration" method="post" action="register.php">
```

When you submitted your form it would post the data to the file `register.php`, which could be used to insert the data into your database. You'd have to create that file as well, of course. More information can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: can u guys give me help on what to do? i am kinda lost

Answer (score 0):

After doing what @anthonygore,
in the register.php file, do the following

1. create connection to database-[See Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)
2. then create query to update to database-[see here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Also in you javascript to validate username and password do the following,

```
function validateForm()
{
   var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
   var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
   var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
   if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
   {
       alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
       return false;
   }
}
```

If you want to validate username and password from database then you have to create connection to database, fetch values and match them with input values using php